# Leer tablas especiales de Excel en R

Tags: excel, r

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy leyendo una tabla desde excel con la función `readxl::read_excel`, la cuestión es que esta tabla tiene un formato especial como el que se muestra en la imagen, en tableau el intérprete de datos logra modificarlo como yo deseo sin embargo quiero generar esta rutina desde `r` y `r` lo lee como lo muestro en la misma imagen, ¿de qué forma puedo leerlo en la forma que lo requiero? si esto no fuera posible al menos quisiera automatizar el relleno de los campos que quedan vacíos para llegar al mismo resultado.

Comment: Finalmente la función `tidyverse::fill` también me ayudó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_excel()` hasta dónde entiendo, no tiene (lamentablemente) ningún tratamiento en particular con las celdas combinadas.

Una alternativa es usar el paquete: [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) que tiene un práctico parámetro `fillMergedCells = TRUE` para considerar de forma efectiva estas celdas

```
library(openxlsx)
df = read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "Libro1.xlsx", fillMergedCells = TRUE,colNames = FALSE)
```

Comment: Efectivamente eso funcionó, el único inconveniente fue que no pude colocar la primera fila como header ya que el argumento ´colNames= TRUE´, refleja el mensaje: formal argument "colNames" matched by multiple actual arguments, así que lo cargué así y lo solucioné con una función adicional.